# How can I create XML Schema documentation that will appear in Eclipse' tooltips?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, documentation, xsd

I have created a custom *XML Schema* that I am using in other parts of an *Android* application. When working with the default *Android* schema, tootips showing documentation for XML attributes are displayed after typing in `android:` or pressing `CTRL-SPACE` (see example image below). What steps do I need to take in order to add this sort of integrated documentation to my custom Schema?

[image: How do I do this?]

**EDIT**

In response to the only answer at the moment, I should explain that I need to know what syntax to use in order to see this documentation, and where to add it to the schema. I have tried adding `<annotation><documentation>blah blah</documentation></annotation>`, however this did not work for me. Is there a specific location for this to be placed, or are there certain needed steps to *compile* the schema with the new documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can config it in "Preferences" page.  "Preferences" -> XML -> XML Catalog, add a user Specified Entries.
[image]

i add a entries for blueprint.

then add the namespace into you xml file as follow
[image]

hope it's useful

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I wasn't entirely clear with my wording... What syntax did you use to add "Defines an alias for a bean..." to your XML Schema?

Comment: ok, first i have the  [blueprint.xsd](http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd) file which showed in the first image, which defines the structs of beans, bean and so on. then use xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" reference to the schema i added

Comment: Thanks for the example! I didn't realize I needed the `<![CDATA[my text]]>` part inside of `<documentation>`.